# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to send a push notification without updating badge number?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

The Worklight adapter code for sending push notifications seems to require that the badge number be provided.  I have the need to send a notification, but, don't want to update the badge number on the app.

When I try to send the notification without the badge (i.e. don't define the badge using: notification.APNS.badge=MYBADGENUMBER), the following error is received:

```
    Mandatory field 'badge' not found.
```

Is there anyway to avoid sending a badge number to update?

Using Worklight 6.0.0.20130909-1459.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: Based on the discussion in the comments I have modified the answer and opened a defect for investigation.*

*Edit 2: This defect is now fixed and will be available in future fixpacks*

The documentation for `WL.Server.createDefaultNotification()` states that the `badge` property is *optional* but in actuality it is *required* by the framework while it *should not be*.

The only workaround seems to be to:

1. Remember the current value of the badge
2. Use badge:0 when sending the push notification
3. Use `WL.Badge` to re-apply the previous badge value from 1

Note that Worklight does not provide any mechanism for updating Badges other than setting or removing (with the exclusion of [the TabBar which allows updating as well)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.TabBarItem.html). So if you send lots of updates you will need to write such a mechanism on your own in order to control the sorting, updating, etc.

Comment: Sending 0 removes the badge.  The issue is not in setting the badge (or managing the badge numbers) in the app.  It's only with the notification.  In the first link above ("How to push notifications without badge number?"), it's stated that if you omit the badge property, it won't update the badge.  This what I want to do with the Worklight push adapter code.  It is NOT "mandatory by Apple".  Apple allows a notification without the badge (by omitting the badge property), but, it doesn't look like the Worklight notification API will allow it.  Seems like a design flaw/bug in the Worklight side.

Comment: And, even the Worklight API states that on WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badge, payload),  the badge is "Optional".  So, it sounds like a bug in the code that is not allowing to be optional.

Comment: Yep. It indeed appears so. Thank you for this question. I have logged a defect. Please mention the following: full Worklight version and build number, and whether you or an IBM business partner or customer. Thanks.

Comment: Done, thanks.  Guess we'll just have to put this notification type on hold until fixed, not sure if a good workaround.

Comment: Since you are a business partner, you can ask your customer to open a PMR if they do not want to wait for the next fixpack and get an ifix in the meanwhile. Tell them to mention in the PMR to move it to Worklight L3 and mention this stackoverflow question.

Comment: @DavidW, PMR received.

Comment: @DavidW, iFix provided to customer.

Comment: @DavidW, since the customer now has a fix for this - can you please mark this question as Answered? Thanks.